# BSOD crashes with no fix solution

Tags: drivers, hardware-failure, bsod, crash

I've recently been experiencing BSOD and complete freezes for the last week. I have a custom built rig as follows:

GPU: GTX 970 Strix

CPU: Intel 2ndGen i7 2600k (1155socket sandybridge 3.4GHZ)

RAM: 16Gb razor(2 x 8GB DDR3)

MOBO: ASRock Z77 Extreme 6

PSU: Crosair CX750W

Storage: OCZ-VERTTEX4 250GB SSD & PNY CS900 120GB SSD

The first BSOD read 'IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL' and the next 'UNEXPECTED_KERNAL_MODE_TRAP'. From here i spoke to with Microsoft Help agents who then found a problem with my Adobe drivers. After a day the computer would then just freeze & stall with no BSOD. I was then advised to wipe my SSDs and reinstall windows but again the problem persisted. I have know been reverted back to windows update 1709 as they think my drivers for my ASrock have not yet been updated to windows 1803. They also logged a power kernal fault which indicated my PSU had critical errors just before my complete freeze today. I have looked into my PSU and the CX model is only designed for basic desktop builds whilst mines a gaming rig. This issue has only risen since the new 1803 windows updates but also as i play more render intensive games.

If anyone could shine some light on which i should try first of A. Getting a new PSU (850W Seasonic has caught my eye) or B. Buy a new MOBO as my drivers are not compatible with 1803 yet seemingly.

Comment: Your problem is not caused by your PSU, if that were the case, you would have had this problem before you installed 1803.  Have you used windbg to confirm the problem drive is indeed the same driver Microsoft indicated was the problem?

Comment: I've recently started to use more than one account online for some games and thought this might have caused the possible PSU problem. Because Microsoft have disabled my windows updates via coding i can't download the windbg Preview from the microsoft app store.

Comment: The PSU is not your problem. Do these freezes happen at random times, or when doing some certain task? I'd also advise to NOT use Microsoft Help agents. As expected they try one thing and revert to the standard "reinstall your OS." Bring it to a local PC shop instead, they're much more knowledgeable.

Comment: It started with high rendering games but then it would just crash using Discord. After installing 1709 patch i've not experienced it as of yet but have been playing games at a lower setting. I know my MOBO isn't the newest but i'm struggling to find a solution so solve these crashes.

Comment: @JamieDoig - `So download the non-preview version of windbg [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools).  Out of curiosity what is the reason, you can't install it, through the store?

Comment: [analyze the dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Comment: They disabled any access to updating frm 1709 to 1803, which appears to affect the microsoft store too. I have had another crash today BSOD SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION. This has only really happened when running two accounts at the same time on Eve online, i had thought since my PSU was a CX 750W, the recent high rendering may have bottlenecked out the PSU? It's either i change the PSU or MOBO as it could be a driver issue with the new 1803 update. Suggestions?

Comment: Jamie, your comment suspects me to believe it's the elusive bad PCIe slot. I've had this problem, and have answered several other questions on here with the same issue. It usually happens with high rendering games and you get a BSOD. And your low graphics gaming helps to reinforce that the slot may be the problem. Try moving your GPU to a different PCIe slot and see what happens. Also, since you're new here, use the @ symbol to ping someone in a comment. I don't get a notification if you don't use @DrZoo.

Comment: @DrZoo Perfect, will try this tonight and get back to you! ^^

Comment: again, analyze the dmp files are share them. everything else is speculation.

Comment: @DrZoo   Thanks for the advice all! I have now tried the GPU in another pci slot and this has solved the bsod issues. I will learn how to analyze dump files with Windbg in the future so thanks very much for the support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the video card to a different PCIe slot solves the BSOD issues in this case. These hardware problems can be hard to detect because it doesn't always give the same error. One good way to suspect this is the problem, is that the BSOD or game crashes happen when playing graphically intense games.